# A new Catalog entry is not visible in Catalogs

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to add a new Catalog entry as "Beauty Products" in addition to Service Catalog and Technical Catalog which is not visible in Catalogs when I login as a user. I have added a category and catalog item as well. Attaching the settings as an image.

[image: Beauty Products]
[image: Catalogs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, you are under **Service Catalog** > **Catalogs**?

If so, you need to add the new catalog by clicking the *plus* button on the top right.

[image]

Then select your Beauty Products catalog from the window, then click *Add here*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[add new catablog entry not working]
I ran into issue when addingg new catablog entry, and found a way to go around this error.

Since Catablog stop updating from 2019, a lot of small issues that might have something to do with incompactability with the newer Wordpress version starts to emerge.

Go to Catablog > Option > Export > Save CSV BackUp File
to save a backup file, add a new item according the the format, delete other items, and import the CSV file again.

This was, you should have a new item in the library that you can modify from.